# Swift: Signing with SHA256 not working like in amazon aws example

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, hash, signature, sha

Hello I want to create a signature for amazon-aws with swift but the given example is resulting other hashes than my functions.

The example is given here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html

and looks like this with JS:

```
var crypto = require("crypto-js");

function getSignatureKey(Crypto, key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate = Crypto.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
    var kRegion = Crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    var kService = Crypto.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    var kSigning = Crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}
```

The input is this:

```
key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'
```

And it should result the following:

```
kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

So my swift solution looks like this:

```
    let kSecret = "AWS4wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.hexEncodedString()
    let kDate = "20120215".hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, key: kSecret!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.hexEncodedString()
    let kRegion = "us-east-1".hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, key: kDate!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.hexEncodedString()
    let kService = "iam".hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, key: kRegion!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.hexEncodedString()
    let kSigning = "aws4_request".hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, key: kService!).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.hexEncodedString()
```

But what I get as result is following:

```
kSecret: "41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559"
kDate: "536c634e5047706e3276437146796a41722f677a6657637a68742b48364f755469772b72436363686868453d"
kRegion: "416e524c31512b47434a624d4a2f4d4945755133574176622b65676c54475159576568674c6179414549383d"
kService: "32624f4c5a514a517a796779626b485230775564583675687844796e66366147512f2f4d41304464506b4d3d"
kSigning: "4652316463434b5472665476524254544245384d646653674a413377663053534e4554317a7a6f2b4f4b6f3d"
```

So the first hash matches but after that none of them match. I even think maybe the SHA256 encoding is not correctly because SHA256 encoding and parsing to hex will always result this length of hashes. But in the given example the hashes are not that long.

What is the problem here?

I also use these helper functions:

```
enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {
    func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, Int(strlen(cKey!)), cData!, Int(strlen(cData!)), &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }
}

extension Data {
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `hmac()` function outputs a base64 encoded string. You then convert that base64 string directly into hex. That's why the length of the hash is wrong.

Comment: So how to do it correctly?

Comment: Your `hmacData: NSData` variable already has the data you actually want. Convert that directly to hex. Don't do the unnecessary base64 conversion in between.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you implemented the final result? I've been having the same issue but still can't get the correct result based on the comment above. If you post it as an answer and it is correct I will happily up vote it as well as be eternally grateful. TIA

Comment: same situation here